# For vectors $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$, $\vec{b}\times\vec{c}$, $\vec{c}\times\vec{a}$, which are linearly dependent, show that they must be parallel.

Tags: linear-algebra

> For vectors $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ show: If vectors  $$\vec{a} \times \vec{b}, \;\vec{b} \times \vec{c},\; \vec{c} \times \vec{a}$$
> are linearly dependent, then they must be parallel.

How would you prove that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are linearly dependent, then we can find real numbers $x,y,z$ such that
$$
 x(a \times b) + y (b \times c) + z(c \times a) = 0.
$$
To get the idea across, assume that $x,y,z \not= 0$. Otherwise you just have to do case work.

Note that $c \cdot (c \times \text{anything}) = 0$. If we dot product the left and right hand sides by $c$, we see that
that$$
 x(a \times b) \cdot c = 0.
$$
Since $x \not= 0$, this shows that all three $a \times b$, $b \times c$, and $c \times a$ are orthogonal to $c$. Repeating this for $a,b$, we see that all three cross products are orthogonal to $a,b,c$. From here, you can deduce that they are all parallel. (Again, more case works)